# How to combine two $(document).ready callbacks with jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to combine these two JavaScript $(document).ready functions together? If so, how?

Code 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "scrollY": 280,
        "scrollX": true,
        "pagingType": "simple",
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    });
});
```

Code 2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table );
    $( tt.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table );

 $( tt.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');


    $('#example').dataTable({

        "scrollY": 280,
        "scrollX": true,
        "pagingType": "simple",
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }



//End of document.ready
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not working guys, I think the .dataTable is being called twice that's why the output is like this: http://i.imgur.com/85COsld.jpg

Comment: So are you saying that it works correctly when you call them separately?

Comment: It's also not working if I separate them. I think the code number 2 is for the boostrap layout.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking if you can move the code inside the second `ready()` into the first, so you only call `ready()` one time? Yes, and it would look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {

        "scrollY": 280,
        "scrollX": true,
        "pagingType": "simple",
        dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"

        }

    });

    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table );

    $( tt.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.dataTables_wrapper');    
} );
```

Comment: It's not working guys, I think the .dataTable is being called twice that's why the output is like this: http://i.imgur.com/85COsld.jpg